# Добавить текст в edit1, не изменив текст

Tags: delphi

Приветики Всем! Наверно глупый вопрос: как в edit1 добавить цифру 1 не изменяя его текста?

Comment: ты сам-то понял, что сказал?

Comment: > текста не меняй @ цифру добавляй

Comment: это нереально прибавит один и при этом не изменять текст

Comment: Это реально если реализовать(самому, ручками) нечто подобное Caption='1'+Text; и прорисовывать сам Caption :)

Comment: Это как добавить цифру к очищенному полю, только не очищая его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так

```
Edit1.text:=Edit1.Text+'1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Если верно понимаю то описать дочерний компонент и переопределить прорисовку, если не верно то как вам ответил предыдущий автор.